# Compounded in-arrears payoff with backward pricing method

Tags: option-pricing

RFR's will be compounded in-arrears, if I have an option on this rate am I forced to use Monte Carlo or are there techniques in the literature that will price path-dependent trades with a backwards pricing method (PDE/lattice etc)?

Comment: It depends on what payoff you are thinking. For many of them, transition from IBORs to RFRs poses no analytical challenge. What product did you had in mind?

Comment: Let’s assume I want to price a caplet type cashflow in Hull-White model in a backwards numerical method, this is an example that doesn’t carry over from IBOR to RFR due to asianisation of the payoff.

Comment: Just to clarify I’m not after closed form solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can price Asian-style options in PDEs, by introducing an extra state variable which is the accumulated Asian variable (in your case the RFR rate). It is well covered in literature, a quick Google search on "pricing Asian options in PDE" should bring plenty of results. For example [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228290123_Efficient_Pricing_of_Asian_Options_by_the_PDE_Approach/link/02bfe513de7010f61c000000/download), equation (3) shows the PDE to solve. Notwithstanding your comment, for caplets on RFR rates in the Hull-White model there are closed-form solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange Mr. Piterbarg.

Comment: What Daneel Olivaw said.

Comment: Pleasure to be here!

Comment: Thank you and welcome. Since posting the question I happened to find the same answer in your book :)

Comment: :-) I did not want to say "read my book" in the answer!